# SQL/MySQL Select items using JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables like this:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tb_item (
  item_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  item_name VARCHAR(100) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (item_id)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tb_item_img (
  item_img_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  item_img_thumb ENUM('0','1') NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
  item_img_image VARCHAR(100) NULL ,
  item_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (item_img_id) ,
  INDEX fk_tb_item_img_tb_item1_idx (item_id ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT fk_tb_item_img_tb_item1
    FOREIGN KEY (item_id )
    REFERENCES tb_item (item_id )
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

And I have one query that I would like to select all items from `tb_item` and **just** one image each item and I won't like to use subquery, I'm using **JOIN** like this:

```
SELECT `item_id`, `item_name`, `item_img_image`
FROM (`tb_item`)
INNER JOIN `tb_item_img` USING ( `item_id` ) 
LIMIT 8
```

But, when the item has more than 1 image, it return more than 1 time. 
When the item has no image, it isn't selected.

So, my question is: is it possible, with a query like this above, select all items and 1 image o NULL to image field. but just once each `item_id`?

Answer (score 0):

No.

To be fair, getting the items when they have no image can be done usint a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. But there is no way, using SQL, to get a join that only matches one of the files that meet the restrictions.

UPDATE: Of course here are not included aggregate functions like MAX() or MIN(), but those do not apply to this case. And with subselects is possible, although heavy :-)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible with inner join.

Because you are using small limit you should use this

```
SELECT 
  `item_id`, 
  `item_name`,  
  (select `item_img_image` from `tb_item_img` where `item_id` = `tb_item`.`item_id`) as `item_img_image`
FROM (`tb_item`) 
LIMIT 8
```

Try also to sort by one of columns from tb_item and then limit to have the same result always .

Comment: yes, this one would be easy. but I'm trying something different. without subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

This query will show all records from two tables -

```
SELECT * FROM tb_item t1
  LEFT JOIN tb_item_img t2
    ON t1.item_id = t2.item_id
```

If you want one record for each `item_id`, then you need to group result. For example -

```
SELECT
  t1.*, GROUP_CONCAT(t2.item_img_id)
FROM tb_item t1
  LEFT JOIN tb_item_img t2
    ON t1.item_id = t2.item_id
GROUP BY
  t1.item_id
```

[GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function returns child values in one cell (comma-separated style).

---

If there is only one `item_img_image` with `item_img_thumb` = 1, then try this query -

```
SELECT
  t1.*, t2.item_img_image -- GROUP_CONCAT(t2.item_img_image)
FROM tb_item t1
  LEFT JOIN tb_item_img t2
    ON t1.item_id = t2.item_id
WHERE
  t2.item_img_thumb = 1
GROUP BY
  t1.item_id
```

...if there are multiple ones, then apply aggregate function, e.g. - GROUP_CONCAT.

Comment: Thanks.. I didn't remember about group by. Now I almost there. the only thing that is working wrong is: the item_img_image should be that one with `item_img_thumb = '1'.

Comment: I found something about what I want with @Devart solution on this  [link](http://www.cafewebmaster.com/mysql-order-sort-group)

Comment: with t2.item_img_thumb=1 that ones without image aren't selected. I want something like "sort by/order_by". but I found that MySQL can't sort before group. =(

Comment: Can you add INSERT satatements (small dataset), and desired result?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will use a "subselect" to resolve this. Is not what I want, but is what I need. Thank you very much!

Comment: t2.item_img_thunb=1 OR t2.item_img_thumb IS NULL